Lambda function deployed through CDK is unable to find the handler
Pretty much sums up the title;
I'm new to CDK, and I've tried to attach a simple handler function to a lambda stack, and create a GET route, all using AWS CDK. I also use Projen to make my life easier.

quotes.ts
import { APIGatewayProxyHandler } from 'aws-lambda';

const quotesHandler: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (event, context) => {
  const quotes = [
    {
      text: "You'll see it when you believe it.",
      author: 'Wayne Dyer, type.fit',
    },
    {
      text: 'Today is the tomorrow we worried about yesterday.',
      author: 'type.fit',
    },
  ];
  const item = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify(item),
  };
};

export default quotesHandler;

main.ts
import { join } from 'path';
import { App, Stack, StackProps } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { LambdaIntegration, RestApi } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway';
import { Code, Runtime, Function } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-lambda';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';

export class MyStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    // define resources here...
    const handlerFunction = new Function(this, 'HelloFunction', {
      runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_LATEST,
      memorySize: 512,
      handler: 'quotes.quotesHandler',
      code: Code.fromAsset(
        join(__dirname, './lambdas'),
      ),
    });

    //Defining a REST API
    let api = new RestApi(this, 'quotes-api', {
      description: 'quotes API',
    });

    let mainPath = api.root.addResource('quotes');
    mainPath.addMethod('GET', new LambdaIntegration(handlerFunction));
  }
}

// for development, use account/region from cdk cli
const devEnv = {
  account: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT,
  region: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION,
};

const app = new App();

new MyStack(app, 'CDK-dev', { env: devEnv });
// new MyStack(app, 'CDK-prod', { env: prodEnv });

app.synth();

CDK deploy returns https://78ldjdffu8.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/prod/,
and https://78ldjdffu8.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/prod/quotes
returns an internal server error.
This is what I get when I try to run the Test option in Lambda, in AWS Console
Response
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "errorMessage": "Error: Cannot find module 'quotes'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.ImportModuleError: Error: Cannot find module 'quotes'",
    "Require stack:",
    "- /var/runtime/index.mjs",
    "    at _loadUserApp (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1087:17)",
    "    at async UserFunction.js.module.exports.load (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1119:21)",
    "    at async start (file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1282:23)",
    "    at async file:///var/runtime/index.mjs:1288:1"
  ]
}

EDIT:
The problem is with not being able to run TS files once it is bundled. If I convert TS to JS by changing the rootDir and outDir of tsconfig to '.', and then build and deploy, the lambda works fine. Is there any way to avoid this I wonder?

It feels like it cannot find the dependency. How do you bundle your lambda?

I'm not sure what you mean by this, but I have used this
code: Code.fromAsset(
join(__dirname, './lambdas'),
),
Which points to the directory which contains the quotes.ts, and this is visible in the console too. Is it because quotes.ts is a typescript file and not a JS file that it's unable to find the quotes file?

Yeah, you cannot run .ts files, they need to be transpiled into js

You're right. Is there any way to be able to run TS files?

You can run ts files in your terminal by npm install -g ts-node typescript '@types/node' then just pick the file to run by ts-node typescript-file.ts.

Also trying adding Code.fromAsset( join(__dirname, './lambdas', 'quotes.ts')

Hi @Ega, quotes.ts is visible in the the bundle. The problem is with not being able to grab the handler function from TS file. When I convert it into JS file, and bundle it, lamnda runs perfectly. I'd like a workaround for this and if you're aware of it, kindly let me know. Thanks in advance.

I also can't imagine why you would use projen. Projen is a cross-compilation tool, typically used for building libraries to be used within CDK projects. If this project is an end-product (which it appears to be based on it deploying resources) then I would remove projen entirely and start fresh from cdk init app and copy your code over.

@therealdakotal you are confusing projen with jsii.

@NKRao no, you need to transpile your ts files to js to run them in a lambda. Use the CDK's NodejsFunction construct, it uses esbuild to bundle your lambda into a single js file.
